# How to use idangero swiper with words on the background then response?

Tags: html, css, swiper.js, idangero

I want to make a carousel like the one on this website:
https://debut-demo.myshopify.com/
The words stick with the picture it belongs to in the carousel.
I tried to use `position: relative` and `position: absolute` to make the words on the background.

1.My HTML

```
<div class="swiper-container">
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <h2>title01</h2>
                <img src="../src/images/background1.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../src/images/background2.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="../src/images/background3.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
```

2.My SCSS

```
    .swiper-container {

    .swiper-slide {
    max-height: 700px;
    position: relative;

    img {
      -webkit-filter: brightness(.8);
      width: 100%;
    }

    h2 {
      top: 245px;
      left: 100px;
      font-size: 4.0625rem;
      z-index: 20;
      position: absolute;
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oza6K.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azWCL.png)

Comment: Hey Branson, what is the current behavior with the code and how is it not matching what you would like? You might find [this W3 article](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) on carousels helpful.

Comment: Hey Jack, now the words are on the background already without response.

Comment: Hey Jack, i added two pictures already. Can you see it please?

Comment: it's the same picture on the same slide from what I can tell.

Comment: I just zoom in the window.